# Perl DBI SQL string error

Tags: sql, string, perl, dbi

I'm writing a perl script that will access a MySQL database to determine whether or not a tool has passed or failed and I'm getting an error when I try to fetchrow_array on the code.

Basically what is happening is I'm looping through a list of tests to see if they have passed or failed so the loop looks like:

```
foreach my $test (@tests){
    $sth = $dbh_k->prepare("select fn_get_test_status(' $test ');");
    $sth->execute();

    my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array();
    print("$test\n");
    print("@data\n");
```

}

and that function returns either the string "passed" or "failed" however I can't figure out how to pull just that one string out and incorporate it into my perl scrip.

I keep getting the error  Use of uninitialized value in join or string at line xx.

Any tips or ideas? thank you

EDIT:
I may have an array of arrays that is being returned as my data type, how to I go into this to check it's contents?

Comment: I switched the fetchrow_array to just fetch() and now I'm pulling an array but I can't print it in regular text.

Comment: What kind of values are in the `@test` array? Is `fn_get_test_status()` a custom mysql function? what is `$fub`? Try [`$sth->dump_results`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#dump_results)

Comment: each @test value is a string with the name of the test. That is a custom SQL function I built and that should read print("$test\n"); sorry I will correct it

Comment: also dump_results() just gave me something that said "1 rows"

Comment: A note in general: prepare the statement outside the loop like `$sth = $dbh_k->prepare('SELECT fn_get_test_status(?);'); foreach...` and call it with `$sth->execute($test);`. That will speed it up and handle escaping for you. See DBI's doc on [prepare](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#prepare).

Comment: thanks I'll make note of that once I get this issue resolved

Comment: Also, set [RaiseError](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#RaiseError). `$sth->{'RaiseError'} = 1;`. It will die giving the error message. - An alternative is to say `$dbh->execute or die $dbh_k->errstr;`.

Comment: I'd turn this into a chat, but it doesn't work yet. Says you don't have enough rep though you do. Anyway: Can you show the SQL code of the function? I've not heard of a query returning an array data type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12756/discussion-between-natesholland-and-simbabque)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution we figured out in the chat:

```
my $sth = $dbh_k->prepare("select fn_get_test_status(?);");
foreach my $test (@tests){
    $sth->execute($test);

    my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array();
    printf "%s: %s\n", $test, @data;
}
```

Main problem were the spaces next to `' $test '`.